# Spermatozoan or spermatozoal?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes, derivational-morphology

Spermatozoon is a single mature sperm cell. The plural is spermatozoa.

Which of the following is correct: "Spermatozoal motility" or "spermatozoan motility"? Or should it be something else?

Googling seems to find both "spermatozoal" and "spermatozoan".

Comment: I was not sure how to tag this - tagging help will be appreciated

Comment: I wonder if "spermatozoic" is also a possibility.

Comment: Apparently people flirted briefly with these ungainly forms [back in the 80s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spermatozoan+motility%2Cspermatozoal+motility%2Csperm+motility&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspermatozoan%20motility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspermatozoal%20motility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csperm%20motility%3B%2Cc0), but common sense seems to have reasserted itself. Nearly everyone today sticks to the straightforward ***sperm motility***.

Comment: Definitely "sperm motility".

Comment: All the answers assume the three forms, -al -an -ic, have the same meaning, which they do not, although they are close. The correct form to use in exact scientific language depends on more context than you've provided. "Sperm motility" is the broadest, most general term, and least demanding to use, which goes some way toward explaining its relative popularity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Pubmed:

- [spermatozoan motility](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22spermatozoan+motility%22+%5Bti%5D) yields 19 results
- [spermatozoic motility](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=spermatozoic+%5Bti%5D) yields 0
- [spermatozoal motility](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22spermatozoal+motility%22+%5Bti%5D) yields 45
- [sperm motility](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22sperm+motility%22+%5Bti%5D) yields 1399

Based on the wider usage, the breadth of journals it's used in, and the more recent use (several in press articles) "sperm motility" is the most popular.

None of the terms seem completely inappropriate, though the low use of spermatozoic (and only use in non-English journals in the 1950s), suggest it may best be avoided.

I think Pubmed is more informative than the dictionary in this case.

*Pubmed searches were for the above terms in title of articles.*

**Edit:** Added sperm motility as mentioned by @FumbleFingers, which is the clear winner.

Comment: Thanks. Actually my specific use includes not only motility but other properties as well - motility was just one example. For motility it is indeed clear that it refers to spermatozoa, since this is mostly a property of mature sperm. But for other properties such as morphology, it may be important to distinguish between spermatozoa and spermatids (non-mature), both of which are sperm - so "sperm morphology" could be vague.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific term, `spermatozoal` seems like a reasonable option.  Originally I did the pubmed searches without the motility term and did not include 'sperm' and it was the winner.

Answer (score 2):

Webster's medical dictionary lists spermatozoan but not spermatozoal or spermatozoic.

Answer (score 2):

The OED lists both *spermatozoan* and *spermatozoic*. Glowbe (Global corpus of web-based English) has 8 instances of *speratozoan*, and none of either *spermatozoic* or *spermatozoal*.

Comment: Although at least four of those eight instances are clearly typos or errors where the noun *spermatozoon* is what is actually called for, one of them is in the exact phrase "spermatozoan motility."

Comment: Here is an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spermatozoan_ADJ%2C+spermatozoic_ADJ%2C+spermatozoal_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) of the three in adjectival usage. I am surprised to note that in 2008 *spermatozoal* outpolled the other two put together.